# Xcode 10 update fails to find header file despite correct path in 'Header Search Paths'

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos-high-sierra, xcode10

Xcode 10 was released 5 days ago and now our code fails to compile (compiled without issue before the update).

The first Cocoa file that gets built in our project fails to find a header despite the correct path in **Header Search Paths**.

I've stared at the error and pored over the settings and nothing comes to my mind. I've googled on things specific to Xcode 10 but don't see anything relevant.

Output from compile:

```
    /Users/joe/src/MyApp/AudioC.mm:9:9: fatal error: 'lib/OSX/foo.h' file not found
    #import "lib/OSX/foo.h"
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Are there any known related issues or potential bugaboos that I'm not aware of for making the jump from Xcode 9 to 10?

Comment: I had to delete my header search paths in one project to get 10 to work.

Comment: Have similar problems but it gets even worse. My XCode 10 crashes on relative paths in header search paths due to exception not allowing non-global paths. Clearly something is broken here.

Comment: The same was happening to me. 'Clean build folder' fixed it for me.

Comment: ~/GitHub/fmdb is not resolving headers for subproject!?